# Small female cat is scared of her brother

Tags: cats, aggression

I recently adopted two kittens a larger brother and a small runt female. They were both so shy and timid when I got them but she was terrified and always hid under the couch. I realized that she is scared of her brother. She always wants to come sit on my lap but when she does the brother comes out angrily and she gets scared and runs away. He takes everything from her and she cowers in the corner keeping her eyes on him. I have showed both of them live equally but I don’t know what to do with their dynamic and it really bothers me because I have to see her running away scared most of the day.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Some more information would help :) How old do you think are both? Do you know about their history (siblings? lived together until now?)? Depending of the age, maybe they are neutered? When was the last visit of them with a vet? And please add a clear question what you want to know, or an aim you want to reach :) So the answers can focus on your primal question/aim.